# Implementing JBehave Navigator

Tags: maven, jbehave

Has anyone got a working solution for implementing jbehave-navigator sucessfully? I'm using version 3.7.5 of jbehave core/navigator.

I have tried importing the dependency and using maven-dependency-plugin to unpack it. This gets the page showing but with formatting issues (everything is out of alignment in all browsers) and none of the data from the report is included.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-jbehave-navigator</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jbehave-navigator</artifactId>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <outputDirectory>target/jbehave/view</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details on what you're trying to do? Like what page/URL you're trying to open in your browser.

Comment: I'm trying to view the navigator.html page. But every time I do, it's never formatted correctly and contains no story data. e.g. http://i.imgur.com/CCl0Ffb.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the following two pages provide some detail on using/unpacking Navigator:

- http://www.pankajnakhat.com/blog1/bdd/03/jbehave-story-navigator-dictionary-of-all-the-steps/
- https://github.com/pnakhat/nav

Take a look at the GitHub project's `pom.xml` file. It seems like there's some additional `resource` configuration, and also an `unpack-view-resources` goal in the `jbehave-maven-plugin`. The GitHub project looks like a working example.

Comment: I was unable to get this example working, however the *Stories.java from the github project did help me get the data reading in correctly (I had put the crossreference in the config method). And to fix the styling I copied the old resources from https://github.com/paul-hammant/StoryNavigator which still work. So I accept your answer as it got me on the right path.